# VS C# simple radio button switch

Tags: c#, radio-button

I've tried to search here for a solution, but none of available seem to work. The two radio buttons are in a group box.

code:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RadioButton senderControl = sender as RadioButton;
            if (!senderControl.Checked)
                return;

            switch ((sender as RadioButton).Text)
            {
                case "radioButton1":
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    comboBox6.Enabled = false;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox4.Enabled = false;
                    textBox4.Text = "000";
                    break;

                case "radioButton2":
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    comboBox6.Enabled = true;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox4.Enabled = true;
                    textBox4.Text = "";
                    break;
            }                 
        }
```

Which doesn't want to work, as in it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your event "radioChecked" is assigned to a single radioButton. You need to attach both radiobuttons to the same event. You can do it this way in the code or your form:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
            radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        }
```

But after that you need to go to Form.Designer.cs file and delete lines of code that assign the event to the radioButtons:

```
this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton_CheckedChanged); // <-- delete
```

Also, your first condition `if (!senderControl.Checked)` is unnecessary, because if you click on radiobutton, then it is checked anyway.

So, here is your piece of code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
            radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        }

private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton senderControl = sender as RadioButton;
            switch (senderControl.Text)
            {
                case "radioButton1":
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    comboBox6.Enabled = false;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox4.Enabled = false;
                    textBox4.Text = "000";
                    break;

                case "radioButton2":
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    comboBox6.Enabled = true;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox4.Enabled = true;
                    textBox4.Text = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I followed what you said, but no difference, I have no idea why. However, I've noticed I didn't have the line you wrote in my Form.Designer.cs (in my case ToolingDesign.Designer.cs)

Comment: Use a breakpoint on the first line of ```radioButton_CheckedChanged``` event and see if you even get inside and tell me if you do.

Comment: interesting, it goes into `RadioButton senderControl = sender as RadioButton;` and also `switch (senderControl.Text)` but never into the `case` itself, so it never triggers the case for some reason. Clicking on radio button triggers the`RadioButton senderControl` and gets into a loop with `switch`

Comment: You can inspect what's inside of "senderControl" when you stop at a breakpoint. There you can see what's the Text property of your control that you pressed on. So you can investigate the reasons why aren't you entering any of the case conditions.

Comment: jesus christ, I'm dumb.. anyways, the case name is supposed to be the actual "text" of the button and not name (radioButton1), so in my case it was "Yes" and "No", it works perfectly now. Don't know how I missed that lol

Comment: Glad to help you! You can check the "Name" property instead if you want: ```switch (senderControl.Name)```